# Run a specific set of lines within a function in a different thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a huge function `(length>4000)` lines. In this function, I have more than 100 variables declared in the beginning. Now, I want to run a specific block of lines in a different thread. For example, I want to run lines `2000-3000` in a different thread. How do I do this?

To scale down the example, this is what I have:

```
int functionA()
{
    .....variables declared......
    .....variables declared......
    printf("hello");
    printf("this");
    printf("is in another");
    printf("thread");
}
```

I want to run the 4 `printf` functions in another thread.

To do this, this is what I've currently done:

```
int functionA()
{
    .....variables declared......
    .....variables declared......
    void functionB()
    {
       printf("hello");
       printf("this");
       printf("is in another");
       printf("thread");
    }
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, functionB, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

I know this is a terrible way to do this. However, there are too many variables to pass in case I want to make `functionB` a new independent function.

Please let me know how to proceed.

Comment: You need to move them in a separate function and pass the right arguments. Also, beware that `printf` is not thread safe, so you must sync the the calls to it, otherwise your output will most likely be a mess.

Comment: Do you want it in C oder C++? You wrote both tags. In C++ i would make a class, define the variables as private, create a class function that does the threading stuff and start a new thread using this function. You have to make sure that the variable access gets controlled, if more than one thread accesses them, by mutexes.

Comment: @Nidhoegger, I just removed the `C++` tag. I'm coding in `C`.
And @MariusBancila, I don't want to move them to a separate function - There are too many variables to pass as arguments and I cannot make them global.

Comment: But you have to move them out of the function or you have to pass the variables via parameters. You could also bundle the used variables in a struct, then you only have to pass that struct.

Comment: If you have 4000+ line function, it's time to do some serious refactoring.

Comment: @user694733, haha yeah. But this is what was given to me and I can't split modules. Too many dependencies.

Comment: Sometimes its better to spend time refactoring and live happily ever after than trying to work around stuff. I did some refactoring today, too, cost me a couple of hours. Now the code is more readable, faster and smaller.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do in your case is: Create a struct containing all the needed variables. Then create a new function with a pointer to that struct as parameter. Then you can create a new thread using that function and you would only have to pass that struct. Also the struct creation will be coded very fast, you just have to put

```
struct nameforstruct {
    //declare vars here, e.g.:
    int somevar;
}
```

around it and change your access to the vars by copy-pasting structname-> in front of it.

Function may then look like:

```
void threadingStuff(struct nametostruct * myvars) {
    if (myvars->somevar == 1) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

That would be in my opinion the fastest way to achieve what you want (and the way with the lessest work). But I would really consider refactoring this to some better approach...

Comment: PlusOne: Even if refactoring to proper modules is done at later time, using structure can be useful as a first step.

Comment: Makes total sense, yes. But is there, by any chance any `pthread` implementation that would allow me to execute the lines by keeping them in the same function? Even the structure method you just gave me seems like a little too much work for a 100 variables which get accessed and initialized in different points over the 2000 lines which I need to thread.
Thank you, btw.

Comment: @user694733: Definitiv true!